# php import csv file into database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a file which I need to import into my database but I like to import 10 record at a time.

e.g. I have 100 records in my .csv file so first time it runs it will start from 0 then it will goto 10 and changes the your to domain.com/importfile.php/?start=10

this is the code I use.

```
$file = fopen($file, "r");
    while (($data = fgetcsv($file, 8000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $county = new County();
        $county->countrycode = $countrycode;
        $county->code = trim($data[0]);
        $county->var_name = $county->mod_write_check( trim($data[1]) );
        $county->name = trim($data[1]);
        $county->statecode = trim($data[2]);
        $save = $county->save();
    }
    fclose($file);
```

I would like to know if this can be done.

Comment: Parse your CSV file into an array. Cache it. Insert entries by 10.

Comment: if the csv file is over 100000 record it fails because it ust time out thats the reason i like to break the file in to 10 records process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using [SplFileObject](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.splfileobject.php) for deailing with files.

Here's a blog that goes thrugh the basics:

http://hakre.wordpress.com/2010/07/25/parsing-csv-files-with-php-spl-style/

The SplFileObject can easily seek but in combination with [limitIterator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.limititerator.php) you can also do:

```
$csv = new SplFileObject('data.csv');
$csv->setFlags(SplFileObject::READ_CSV);

foreach(new LimitIterator($csv, 0, 500) as $line){
  #save $line
}
```

[Code snippet source](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?710835-Spliting-a-75mb-CSV-into-managable-file-sizes)

Comment: I need to start from 1 to 10 first time then 11 to 20. this does start from when ever i wont but the end record his always same.

Comment: will this break if i wont to add a csv file which is over 400mb

Comment: how do I count number of records in this csv file.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `$seek = ftell($file);` [ftell documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftell.php) and `fseek($file, $seek+1)` 
you will need to carry in your session or somewhere else the value of `$seek`

Comment: i like to start at 0 when loop reach 10 then it refresh the page but this time it start from 11, i like to ignore the session to keep information.

Comment: You can have a variable just outside your loop that counts how many records you added and have a conditional and in the while loop. 
`$inserted = 0 ;
while(data = fgetcsv($file, 8000, ",")) !== FALSE && $inserted <= 10){
$inserted++ ;
}
$seek = ftell($file);
`